# Find the modulus of the holomorphic function f at zero given $|f(e^{iw})| = e^{w(2\pi-w)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a function nonvanishing holomorphic on the closed unit disk $U(0,1)$. $|f(e^{iw})| = e^{w(2\pi-w)}$,$0 \leqslant w < 2\pi$, then what would be the modulus of $f(0)$?

By Cauchy integral formula, $f(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(e^{iw})dw$.

Comment: And now apply $\left|\int f(z) dz\right| \leq \int |f(z)| dz$

Comment: The given formula implies $|f|$ is discontinuous at $1$ unless $\theta =0.$ In that case, there is no unique solution.

Comment: Then I would get $|f(0)| \leqslant |e^{(w(2\pi-w)}|$, but what can I do next?

Comment: sorry that I misprint it @zhw.

Comment: That depends on the roots of $f$ on the unit disc. Did you forget a condition?

Comment: @WimC yes，I have edited it

Comment: What do you know about the function $z \mapsto \log \lvert f(z)\rvert$?

Comment: I know nothing about it, are there any other ways to approach this problem? @DanielFischer

Comment: You should know a little about harmonic functions.

Comment: Yes, I know about Dirichlet problem and poisson representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Jensen's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula) $$ \log \lvert f(0) \rvert = \frac1{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} t (2 \pi - t) \mathrm{d}t = \frac{2\pi^2}3.$$

Comment: You don't really need Jensen, just the fact that $\log |f|$ is harmonic on the closed disc.

Comment: I know nothing about log|f|, do you have other ways to approach this?

Comment: I think zhw is right.

Comment: @zhw Yes, without roots that's more straightforward.